# Using Powershell how can I retrieve "Policy Application Status" from an Exchange Mobile Device?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, mobile-devices, activesync

I am writing a script to process quarantined mobile devices in exchange 2019 and before allowing them I need to confirm that the "Policy application status" is "Applied in full" but I am not seeing that as an option to reference using Get-MobileDevice.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are looking for to retrieve the Policy application status is:

[Get-MobileDeviceStatistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/devices/get-mobiledevicestatistics?view=exchange-ps)

Here is an example that will pull the `DevicePolicyApplicationStatus` :

`Get-MobileDeviceStatistics -Mailbox mailboxusername | select DeviceID, DeviceType, DevicePolicyApplicationStatus`

An example MS gives that might be helpful as well:

> This example uses the Get-CASMailbox cmdlet to determine who in the
>   organization has an Exchange ActiveSync mobile device. For each mobile
>   device, the Exchange ActiveSync device statistics are retrieved.

`$UserList = Get-CASMailbox -Filter {HasActiveSyncDevicePartnership -eq $true -and -not DisplayName -like "CAS_{*"} | Get-Mailbox; $UserList | foreach {Get-MobileDeviceStatistics -Mailbox $_.Identity}`

Comment: Thanks so much jrider!